# window.close não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Estou implementando o Dialog do Jquery UI em minha aplicação. Quando o dialog é fechado ele deve fechar a janela atual utilizando o método `window.open();` do javascript.

Porém isto não ocorre, e ainda é exibido o seguinte erro no console:

```
Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.
```

Já a algum tempo estou procurando pela solução no Google, mas tudo que encontrei ainda não foi suficiente. Um exemplo de solução aceita massivamente mas que não resolveu o meu problema foi o uso do seguinte código (ou variações semelhantes):

```
window.open('', '_self', '');
window.close();
```

Simplifiquei o código da minha aplicação para utilizar de exemplo neste [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayconfsbrito/9b8q5j9c/), apesar de que pelo JSFiddle não é exibido a mensagem de erro, e nem a janela é fechada.

Comment: Já experimentou utilizar o jQuery.Dialog () da jQueryUI ??

Comment: É exatamente ele que estou utilizando.

Comment: O método `window.open` retorna a referência para a janela aberta, onde pode usar o `window.close` nesse mesmo objeto. Consegue testar isso?

Comment: Lá no fiddle: `parent.window.close();` dispara.

Comment: @brasofilo sim, dispara sim.

Comment: @Wakim qual atributo de window dispara esta referência?

Comment: O próprio `window.open` retorna a referência para o objeto `window` da janela aberta. É só guardar ele e usar depois quando quiser fechar.

Comment: @Wakim então eu posso passá-lo por parâmetro para a função do dialog e utilizá-lo lá?

Comment: Sim, acredito que pode passar, por causa da chamada ao `dialog` você vai "guardar" ela numa closure, acredito que com isso o objeto vai estar disponível na ação do dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri a razão do problema que acontece quando a aba do navegador é reaberta/ressuscitada, ou seja, no Chrome quando eu reabro a janela através do atalho `Ctrl + Shift + T`.

Como estou testando este controller exaustivamente preciso preencher um formulário com muitos campos, para não ter que preenchê-los novamente eu reabro a aba a partir deste atalho, então quando o comando `window.close()` é executado o valor de window não é conhecido, pois a aba é uma `orphan window` (janela órfão).

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda, mas somente após alterar completamente a minha forma de testar que encontrei a causa do problema.

Answer (score 6):

Você não consegue usar `window.close` em janelas que não foram abertas pelo script em questão, e é isso mesmo que a mensagem está dizendo.

Lembre-se que você tem o `self.close()` caso se trate da mesma janela:

```
<a href="self.close ()">Fechar esta janela</a>
```

Mas de qualquer forma, os browsers oferecem algumas restrições para estes usos para evitar abusos, restringindo aos scripts fecharem janelas abertas por scripts, ou com certas condições especiais (depende da implementação de cada browser).

**Simplificando um pouco:**

- O *script* da "página anterior", que criou a janela nova é que pode fechar a janela com `window.close`.
- Para usar o `self.close`, por outro lado, normalmente a janela tem que ter sido aberta por um script.

<sub>Como a implementação varia um pouco de caso a caso, se alguém tiver mais alguma consideração importante, ponha nos comments que eu incremento a resposia</sub>

Comment: Utilizei self.close; e também não funcionou. É exatamente isto que a mensagem alerta.

Comment: O script em questão é chamado diretamente pela página sim, executando o método ajaxSubmit a partir de um onclick em um botão.

Comment: Mas onde está o close? No script ou na janela aberta? Procure editar a pergunta e acrescentar todos os detalhes, se possível.

Comment: No script, dentro do método chamado pelo botão.

Comment: e o script está na janela que abriu o popup, ou no source da própria janela do popup?

Comment: Nem na minha app nem no fiddle self.close(); fechou a janela.

Comment: mas seu fiddle não abriu janela nenhuma, como vai fechar?

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar dialogos jQuery faça da seguinte forma:

```
$(seletor).dialog({
// opcoes que eu quero
});
```

Para fechar o dialogo você pode utilizar o botão que já está disponivel no dialogo ou utilizar o comando close:

```
$(seletor).dialog("close");
```

Uma forma que eu tenho feito para evitar ficar selecionado é guardar a selecao em uma variavel global:

```
window.meuDialogo = $(seletor).dialog({
// Minhas opcoes
});

function fechaDialogo (){
  window.meuDialogo.dialog("close");
}
```